# Orchestrator 2012 vs 2016

Tags: windows, operations-orchestration

I'm still trying to improve my skills. Right now I'm testing Microsoft Orchestrator 2012 and it looks like a nice feature. I was reading about Microsoft Orchestrator 2016 here https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/upgrading-system-center-orchestrator-2012-r2-to-2016, and so here is the question, is Orchestrator 2016 better than 2012, should I upgrade or stay with the previous version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use Orchestrator 2016 since it is the latest version. When you're using any product you count on its support. Also, most new improvements become available for newer versions, so the latest version is more demanded.